# how to use curdate to implement a query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have DB which are having tables for every day like "`2013-05-29`". 
I have a requirement that I should use the "`select`" statement for the current date.
I am trying

```
select * from (SELECT SUBSTR(CURDATE(),1,10))
```

I am getting error

```
Error Code: 1248
```

Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: the name of your table is the date? example, `SELECT * FROM \`2013-05-29\``?

Comment: Yes i'm using the above syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a dynamic sql,

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `', SUBSTR(CURDATE(),1,10), '`');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/834fb/1)